# how to prevent access of hard disc from guest user in window 7 ?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, security

i want to restrict guest user from access the hard disc data, so how it could be,
i goes through this way 
 gpcedit.mc,
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer

Hide these specified drives in My Computer
 if you want to just hide the drives but still allow direct access (e.g. from run prompt, etc.) to the drives. 
Find Prevent access to drives from My Computer to hide the drive and prevent access to it.
In whichever settings dialog, choose the Enabled radio button and choose the drive(s) you want to restrict. As of Windows 7

it hides the hard disc partition but it can allow to access data to the guest user. kindly help me urgent response reqired

Comment: You can do this with "Permissions" settings. The trouble is that if you do this to the OS drive the guest user won't be able to run any programs.

Comment: how to go with permissions settings.???

Answer (score 1):

Right click the folder or drive you wish to set permissions on, click properties then go to security.

If you need more information:
http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Remember Windows has a way to access files on not mounted partitions... no need for a mount point, no letter, no folder where it is mounted.

Search for command `start \\?\Volume{...GUID_of_the_partition...}` and for command `mountvol` to get the GUIDs.

It let you read/write onto any partition present that has FAT/FAT12/FAT16/FAT32/vFAT/exFAT/NTFS format... no need to even have ACL rigths, it bypass them.

It can be considered a BIG Back Door... as well as a way to recover from damaged ACL (aka, permissions).

Only way to avoid is to use a Live Linux (or a one installed) and change type of partitions to 83 if MBR or 8300 if GPT... so windows does not even assign a GUID to them.

Warning: beware what you do using that... you have plenty access to do wahtever wanted in whatever folder you want... all actions takes a lot more time than when partition is mounted.

Other solution... use VeraCrypt or similar to encrypt the partition (if on Linux use LUKs, etc).

Beware to launch that "start" command... if you launch it as SYSTEM (use task manager to do it) you can gain full access also to system partition.

That combined with this i will comment is a high risk.

You can gain very easy SYSTEM privileges (more than admin) just creating a schedule task with you own user account, and then changing the user that runs it to "SYSTEM"... then execute it and it is run under SYSTEM user... that special user has no restrictions, does not check ACL rights, etc.

Well to be worst... creating such task can be done by command line without admin rights, yes, can be done... so a normal windows user can gain SYSTEM rights on any running Windows... no way to avoid it.

If windows uses "polices" it is a bit more complicated (i will not tell how to do such, hope it can be understood... VIRUSES must not learn that way of doing things) but it is not blocked.

You can not protect the actual booted system partition, but the rest yes... fully encrypt them is the only real way, all the rest fail by running on SYSTEM account an access to \?\Volume{...GUID...}.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.